# joining a table on 2 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pull a person and their supervisor names from a table. The `persons` table has the `supervisor_id` and the `person_id`. The `names` table has `name_id` and a `Full Name` field.  If I join `Person` ON either `supervisor_id` or `person_id`, how do I get the other to display as well?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: `JOIN` is what you need

Comment: JOIN twice, the first time for person, the second time for supervisor.

Comment: You need to join twice on the names table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join twice, one for each relationship you have:

```
SELECT
    -- Persons' columns
    P.*,

    -- Superviser name columns
    SN.*,

    -- Person name columns
    PN.*
FROM
    persons AS P
    LEFT JOIN names AS SN ON P.supervisor_id = SN.name_id
    LEFT JOIN names AS PN ON P.person_id = PN.name_id
```

Or you can join with an `OR` clause, but you won't be able to know which record did you join with unless you check with a `CASE`.

```
SELECT
    -- Persons' columns
    P.*,

    -- name columns
    N.*,

    IsSupervisor = CASE WHEN P.supervisor_id = N.name_id THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END

FROM
    persons AS P
    LEFT JOIN names AS N ON 
        P.supervisor_id = N.name_id OR
        P.person_id = N.name_id
```

This last approach will display 2 rows as it will match either one or the other on different occasions, not both with the same `persons` row (as the first example).

Answer (score 1):

A (self)join is what you need:

```
select p.*, supervisor=ps.name
from Person p join person ps on p.supervisor_id=ps.id
```